# Potential memory leak when releasing a Gradient Brush in direct2D?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, directx-11, direct2d

I have a simple C++ program reduced to 272 lines of code that initializes Direct2D, then performs a loop of 1000 operation where it simply creates an ID2D1GradientStopCollection followed by the creation of the using ID2D1LinearGradientBrush, then releases them immediately (Release count falls to zero on the calls to Release thus indicating that they should normally be unallocated).

However, after each execution of this loop, I see the memory reserved by the process increasing, and it is released only at the end, once the direct2D factories and devices are released, instead of being released after each call to linearGradientBrush->Release() and gradientStopCollection->Release() as I would expect.

The strange thing is that when I create/delete a SolidColorBrush instead of a LinearGradientBrush (still creating/deleting the gradientStopCollection) then there is no more memory leak observed.

Is this something I did wrong, causing for example the gradientStopCollection to still be allocated because still used by the brush? (But I do not see in that case why the reference count after the call to Release on the two objects falls to zero; and also, if I add an AddRef or remove a Release in order to trigger the wrong count of AddRef/Release on the objects (and get a non zero reference count situation at the end of the program) then the Direct2D debug layers indicates a fault inside d2d1debug3.dll calling kernelbase.dll on the call stack, thus showing that the AddRef/Release count is correct; yet I still observe this memory leak with the TaskManager).

Any help on how to resolve this would be appreciated

```
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <commctrl.h>

    // DirectX header files.
    #include <d2d1_1.h>
    #include <d3d11.h>
    #include <d3d11_1.h>


    bool performAllocUnallocTestLoop(ID2D1DeviceContext* in_deviceContext) {
        ID2D1GradientStopCollection* gradientStopCollection;
        int i;
        ID2D1LinearGradientBrush* linearGradientBrush;
        int cnt;
        ULONG nb;
        D2D1_GRADIENT_STOP gradientStops[2];
        HRESULT hr;
        ID2D1SolidColorBrush* solidColorBrush;

        gradientStops[0].color = D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::Yellow, 1);
        gradientStops[0].position = 0.0f;
        gradientStops[1].color = D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::ForestGreen, 1);
        gradientStops[1].position = 1.0f;

        cnt = 1000;
        for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
            hr = in_deviceContext->CreateGradientStopCollection(gradientStops, 2, D2D1_GAMMA_2_2, D2D1_EXTEND_MODE_CLAMP, &gradientStopCollection);
            if (!SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                return false;
            }

            hr = in_deviceContext->CreateLinearGradientBrush(D2D1::LinearGradientBrushProperties(D2D1::Point2F(0, 0), D2D1::Point2F(150, 150)), gradientStopCollection, &linearGradientBrush);
            if (!SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                gradientStopCollection->Release();
                return false;
            }

            /*
                // This code is commented and creates a solidColorBrush instead of a linearGradientBrush.
                // Uncomment this code and comment the creation of the linearGradientBrush above instead and the leak disappears.

            hr = in_deviceContext->CreateSolidColorBrush(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::Yellow, 1), &solidColorBrush);
            if (!SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                gradientStopCollection->Release();
                return false;
            }
            */

            nb = linearGradientBrush->Release(); // Comment this line and the linearGradientBrush creation, then uncomment the solidColorBrush creation/release instead
                                 // and the memory leak disappears.
            // nb = solidColorBrush->Release();
            nb = gradientStopCollection->Release();
        }

        return true;
    }

    int main_test_function(ID2D1DeviceContext* in_deviceContext) {
        int i;

        MessageBoxW(NULL, (WCHAR*)L"Before", (WCHAR*)L"Before", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_SETFOREGROUND);

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (!performAllocUnallocTestLoop(in_deviceContext)) {
                MessageBoxW(NULL, (WCHAR*)L"Some creation failed", (WCHAR*)L"Some creation failed", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_SETFOREGROUND);
                return 0;
            }

            if (MessageBoxW(NULL, (WCHAR*)L"After performed another 1000 create/delete of gradientStopCollection+linearGradientBrush (leak observed in TaskManager, resource NOT released)", (WCHAR*)L"After", MB_OKCANCEL | MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_SETFOREGROUND) == IDCANCEL) {
                break;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

    // _____________________________________________________________
    // _ WinMain part: init/dest D3D and D2D factories and devices.
    // _____________________________________________________________

    struct TD2DFactoriesAndDevices {
        ID2D1Factory1* d2dFactory;

        ID3D11Device1* d3dDevice;
        IDXGIDevice* dxgiDevice;
        ID2D1Device* d2dDevice;
        ID2D1DeviceContext* d2dDeviceContext;
    };

    void destFactoriesAndDevices(TD2DFactoriesAndDevices* in_struct) {

        if (in_struct == NULL) {
            return;
        }

        if (in_struct->d3dDevice != NULL) {
            in_struct->d3dDevice->Release();
            in_struct->d3dDevice = NULL;
        }
        if (in_struct->dxgiDevice != NULL) {
            in_struct->dxgiDevice->Release();
            in_struct->dxgiDevice = NULL;
        }
        if (in_struct->d2dDevice != NULL) {
            in_struct->d2dDevice->Release();
            in_struct->d2dDevice = NULL;
        }
        if (in_struct->d2dDeviceContext != NULL) {
            in_struct->d2dDeviceContext->Release();
            in_struct->d2dDeviceContext = NULL;
        }

        if (in_struct->d2dFactory != NULL) {
            in_struct->d2dFactory->Release();
            in_struct->d2dFactory = NULL;
        }

        CoUninitialize();
    }

    bool initFactoriesAndDevices(TD2DFactoriesAndDevices* in_struct,
                                     const wchar_t*& out_error) {
        HRESULT hr;
        D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS options;
        ID3D11Device* d3dDevice;
        UINT createDeviceFlags;
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE driverType;

        if (in_struct == NULL) {
            out_error = L"Can not use NULL pointer";
            return false;
        }

        in_struct->d3dDevice = NULL;
        in_struct->dxgiDevice = NULL;
        in_struct->d2dDevice = NULL;
        in_struct->d2dDeviceContext = NULL;

        in_struct->d2dFactory = NULL;

        // init DCOM
        if (CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED) != S_OK) {
            out_error = L"Could not init DCOM";
            return false;
        }

        // Create the Direct2D factory.
        ZeroMemory(&options, sizeof(D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS));
    #if defined(_DEBUG)

        options.debugLevel = D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL_INFORMATION;
        // options.debugLevel = D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL_NONE;
    #endif

        hr = D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED,
                                       options, &in_struct->d2dFactory);
        if (!SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
            in_struct->d2dFactory = NULL;
            out_error = L"D2D1CreateFactory failed";
            CoUninitialize();
            return false;
        }

    __create_devices:

        // Create the D3D device on default adapter.
        createDeviceFlags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT;
        createDeviceFlags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_SINGLETHREADED;
    #ifdef _DEBUG
        createDeviceFlags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
    #endif

        // Creating the d3dDevice
        in_struct->d3dDevice = NULL;

        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] =
        {
            D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
            D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
            D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
            D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
            D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
            D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2,
            D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1
        };


        hr = D3D11CreateDevice(
            nullptr,
            D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
            0,
            createDeviceFlags,
            featureLevels,
            ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels),
            D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
            &d3dDevice,
            nullptr,
            nullptr
            );



        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            in_struct->d3dDevice = NULL;
            goto __create_failed;
        }

        hr = d3dDevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Device1),
                                              (void**)(&in_struct->d3dDevice));
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            in_struct->d3dDevice = NULL;
            goto __create_failed;
        }

        d3dDevice->Release();

        // Get a DXGI device interface from the D3D device.
        in_struct->dxgiDevice = NULL;
        hr = in_struct->d3dDevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice),
                                           (void**)(&in_struct->dxgiDevice));
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            in_struct->dxgiDevice = NULL;
            goto __create_failed;
        }

        // Create a D2D device from the DXGI device.
        hr = in_struct->d2dFactory->CreateDevice(in_struct->dxgiDevice,
                                                         &in_struct->d2dDevice);
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            in_struct->d2dDevice = NULL;
            goto __create_failed;
        }

        // Create a device context from the D2D device, to create the
                // resources.
        hr = in_struct->d2dDevice->CreateDeviceContext(
                D2D1_DEVICE_CONTEXT_OPTIONS_NONE, &in_struct->d2dDeviceContext);
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            in_struct->d2dDeviceContext = NULL;
            goto __create_failed;
        }

        // Setting isCreated
    __after_create_devices:

        return true;


    __create_failed:
        destFactoriesAndDevices(in_struct);

        out_error = L"Could not create the devices";
        return false;
    }

    int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                             LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
        int result;
        const wchar_t* _error;
        TD2DFactoriesAndDevices _struct;

        if (!initFactoriesAndDevices(&_struct, _error)) {
            MessageBoxW(NULL, (WCHAR*)L"An error occured", _error,
                                           MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            return 0;
        }

        result = main_test_function(_struct.d2dDeviceContext);

        destFactoriesAndDevices(&_struct);

        return result;
    }
```

This has been tested on two different machines, and the leak appears on x86/x64, debug/release plateforms

Comment: You might be seeing some internal caching behavior or something similar, you could try to do more iterations like 100K or 1M and see if anything changes. I wouldn't worry too much unless it's leaking indefinitely. In any case tight alloc/release is not a pattern that should be used for d2d objects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is indeed leaking indefinitely; this is discussed also [on the MS forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e80729b9-9491-4971-a80c-17f4f14262e6/potential-memory-leak-when-releasing-a-gradient-brush-in-direct2d-?forum=vcgeneral); on a version of the code allocating/unallocating only bitmaps, this leads to E_OUTOFMEMORY despite the API always returning 0 on calls to Release for the refcount.

Comment: Try to call BeginDraw -> EndDraw in the loop just after the release, seems your device context is not flushed. Since you provide your own d3d device, you can get the immediate context from it and call Flush manually too. That should make issue disappear (can put more detailed explanation about it in answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour, considering your code.

Internally, Direct3D11 does some resource tracking, and calling release will only mark the resource for deletion, resource will be effectively deleted if the following conditions are met:

- DeviceContext is Flushed
- Resource external counter is 0 (the one returned by Release)
- Resource internal counter is 0, this is incremented when your resource is attached, detached from the pipeline (in your case Direct2D handle it)

Since in your loop you do not flush at all, the resources are created on the GPU, but only marked for deletion.

There are several ways to flush device:

- When you call EndDraw (or present on the Swapchain), to display on the screen.
- When you manually perform Flush on the Direct3D Device Context (please note that you should not call Flush manually if you actually perform rendering on the screen, since Present/EndDraw will take care of that)
- When you map a resource for cpu readback (out of scope in your use case I guess)
- When the internal command buffer is full (since in your case you do not perform any drawing calls, if never gets filled).

In Direct3d11 case, you should also eventually call ClearState (this resets the whole pipeline tho), but since Direct2D normally takes care of unassigning internal resources, this should not be needed either in your use case.